# Chart.js: colouring tooltip labels

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

[image]

I can't find it in the docs, does anyone know how I can make those grey squares in the tool tip the same color as the lines, and potentially label each one? (High, Low, Average)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like you're not setting properly the pointColor property on your datasets.

For each of your datasets, just set **pointColor** to the same value as **strokeColor**.

Something like, in the first dataset :

```
    strokeColor: "rgba(1,220,1,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(1,220,1,1)",
```

And in the second dataset :

```
    strokeColor: "rgba(220,1,1,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(220,1,1,1)",
```

And so on...

[Here's a jsfiddle to illustrate the point : http://jsfiddle.net/rdtome/aa2j9rut/](http://jsfiddle.net/rdtome/aa2j9rut/).